# How to prevent BeanInstantiationException when Spring controller request attribute is an interface

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

I am attempting to create a Spring controller test using JUnit and Mockito. I am currently using mockMvc as my approach but the main issue that I am encountering is that all of the controller methods are defined as taking an interface as an argument and that results in a BeanInstantiationException when trying to run the test. Here is an example of a possible controller definition:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test/testController")
public class TestController {

@RequestMapping("/test")
public ModelAndView test(@RequestAttribute("list") final List<String> testList) {
    testList.add("test");
    return new ModelAndView("testing");
}

}
```

Since this example defines the `test()` method as taking a List as an argument there will be this exception `Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface` when running the test:

```
@InjectMocks
private TestController testController;
    
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {   
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(testController).build();
}

@Test
public void practiceTest() throws Exception {   

    this.mockMvc.perform(
            post("/test/testController/test").with(x -> {
                x.setAttribute("list", new ArrayList<String>());
                return x;
            })
            )
    .andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(view().name("testing"));
}
```

The obvious solution here would be to update the controller methods to use regular classes instead of interfaces when specifying the arguments they will take, but unfortunately this is not possible due to a requirement that the controller method code is not changed. I have tried it and verified that that does indeed work, but isn't really a usable solution since I will not be able to make the needed changes.

Is there any other way to stop this error from occurring in this kind of scenario?

Comment: The fact that it tries to instantiate the `List` is basically already a sign something is wrong, as that should only happen if it cannot find the attribute in question. Making it `ArrayList` might let it appear to work, but it really isn't. So what you should do is fix your test, I suppose. Instead of `with` you should be using `requestAttr`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried updating to `post("/test/testController/test").requestAttr("list", list)`  (list variable just being a new array list) but I am still facing the same issue.